# Making an array of objects of few classes in another class

Tags: c++, arrays, object

im making a project which simulates exam, and i came across the problem. I have one base class "task", and 3 inheriting classes of the "task" class. Then in new class task collection, i have to make an array, where i will put objects of all 3 inheritings classes from "task". Additionaly, all have to be done in task collection class, not in main function.

Code looks like:

```
class Task
{
    public:
        string contents;
};

class Task4Answ : public Task
{
    public:
        string a,b,c,d;
    Task4Answ(string contents1,string a1,string b1,string c1,string d1)
    {
        contents=contents1;
        a=a1;
        b=b1;
        c=c1;
        d=d1;
    }
};

class TaskNumber : public Task
{
    public:
        int right;
    TaskNumber(string contents1, int pop)
    {
        contents=contents1;
        right=pop;
    }
};

class TaskString : public Task
{
     private:;
        string poprawna;
    public:
    ZadanieNumer(string tresc1,string pop)
    {
        contents=contents1;
        poprawna=pop;
    }
};

class TaskCollection
{
    // Here i need to make an array which contains the objects of 3 classes, and method which will put them into array
};
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>>` ? (and probably virtual destructor to enable `dynamic_cast`) (or `variant` instead of inheritance).

Comment: Oh that looks a little bit hard for me, is there a possibility that i could use base class Task in some easier way?

Comment: What do you want to do with your collection ?

Comment: I want to draw a random test of tasks from it, get answers from user, and check if they're right or not.

Comment: @DarekD -- *Oh that looks a little bit hard for me* -- Well at some point you will need to learn C++.  `std::vector<Task*>` or `std::array<Task*, 3>` and from there, graduate to using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>>` or `std::array<std::unique_ptr<Task>,3>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Task
{
    std::string content;
public:
    explicit Task(const std::string& title) : content{title} {}
    virtual ~Task() = default;

    virtual bool check(std::istream& is) const = 0;

};

class TaskNumber : public Task
{
    int value;
public:
    TaskNumber(const std::string& title, int value) : Task{title}, value{value} {}

    bool check(std::istream& is) const override
    {
        int i;
        is >> i;
        return i == value;
    }

};

class TaskString : public Task
{
    std::string value;
public:
    TaskString(const std::string& title, const std::string& s) : Task{title}, value{s} {}

    bool check(std::istream& is) const override
    {
        std::string s;
        is >> s;
        return s == value;
    }
};

class TaskCollection
{
public:
    void addTask(std::unique_ptr<Task> task) { tasks.push_back(std::move(task)); }

    void run(std::istream& is) {
        for (auto& task : tasks) {
            std::cout << (task->check(is) ? "Success\n" : "Failed\n");
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>> tasks;
};

int main()
{
    TaskCollection tasks;

    tasks.addTask(std::make_unique<TaskString>("t1", "Hello"));
    tasks.addTask(std::make_unique<TaskString>("t2", "world"));
    tasks.addTask(std::make_unique<TaskNumber>("t3", 42));

    std::string s{"Hi world 42"};
    std::stringstream ss{s};
    tasks.run(ss);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/yCx3jc)

You use virtual method to do the specific job according to the base interface.

Answer (score -1):

I assume `ZadanieNumer(string tresc1, string pop)` is a translation mistake and it should be `TaskString(string contents1, string pop)`.

Now I'm not sure what the problem is, but given your definition, `class TaskCollection` could be as simple as:

```
class TaskCollection
{
    private:
        Task collection[3];

    public:
        TaskCollection(Task4Answ task1, TaskNumber task2, TaskString task3)
        {
            collection[0] = task1;
            collection[1] = task2;
            collection[2] = task3;
        }
}
```

I used this main function to test:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Task4Answ t1("contents", "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1");
    TaskNumber t2("contents", 2);
    TaskString t3("contents", "3");

    TaskCollection tc(t1, t2, t3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but the thing is i need to initialize everything inside the classes, and there put objects to an array.

Comment: Okay. Move the t1, t2, t3 declarations inside the TaskCollection constructor. Eg. `TaskCollection(void) { collection[0] = Task4Answ("contents", "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"); collection[1] = TaskNumber("contents", 2); collection[2] = TaskString("contents", "3"); }`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was something i was looking for !

Comment: @DarekD That is unlikely. This cannot work, unless you want to throw away the derived class part.

Comment: Ohh thought it will be fast simple solution, cause i have to do something to create objects inside this class, and assign them to array.

Comment: This solution will not work.  You're slicing the objects placed in the array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is right - the objects will be sliced and act like the base class. If you don't want that, change the `collection` array to `Task* collection[3];` and add `new` before each of the constructors. The array will then contain pointers to each derived class instance and they will act like the derived class through polymorphism.

Comment: And then you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: lol. It's a "memory leak" if every `new` is a "memory leak" until its deletion. Happy for someone to offer the corresponding destructor, though I suspect it wont contribute much to the question.